# mysqli_connect_error vs mysqli_connect_errno()

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm wondering which one should I use? `mysqli_connect_error` or `mysqli_connect_errno`

```
public function connect() {

    $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if (!$this->connection->connect_error) {

        die("Connection Failed" . " " . $this->connection->connect_error);

    }

}
```

Or

```
public function connect() {

    $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if (!$this->connection->connect_errno) {

        die("Connection Failed" . " " . $this->connection->connect_error);

    }

}
```

Comment: You should remove '!' from both of if clause as connect_error and connect_errno return true value if an error exists.

Answer (score 3):

For your question it's just irrelevant, you can use either.

But let me suggest you a better way.
Instead of checking for the errors manually, just tell mysqli to report errors automatically:

```
public function connect()
{
   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
   $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
}
```

It will give you a more informative error message and it will work for all mysqli commands, so you will need no error checking for prepare/execute and other mysqli commands as well.